# Can there be a measurable set that integrals have the same given value if their integral on $\mathbb{R}$ are the same?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We know for an integrable function $f$, if $\int_\mathbb{R} f=1$, then $\forall \lambda\in [0,1] $, there exists a measurable set $E$ that $\int_E f=\lambda$.

Now consider integrable functions $f$ and $g$, if $\int_\mathbb{R} f=1=\int_\mathbb{R} g$, then $\forall \lambda\in [0,1] $, does there exist a measurable set $E$ that $\int_E f=\lambda=\int_\mathbb{E} g$?

Answer (score 19):

Yes.  A consequence of [Lyapunov's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov%27s_theorem#Lyapunov.27s_theorem).

> The range of a non-atomic vector measure is closed and convex.

In this case, the vector measure $m$ with values in $\mathbb R^2$ is
$$
m(E) = \left(\int_E f, \int_E g\right)\qquad\text{for all Lebesgue measurable } E \subseteq \mathbb R.
$$
The hypothesis shows $(1,1)$ is in the range.  And clearly $(0,0)$ is in the range.  So (by convexity) all $(\lambda,\lambda)$ with $0 \le \lambda \le 1$ are also in the range.

Comment: Can you give more details, please? Which of his theorems, perhaps a reference, and an indication how the result follows?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Lyapunov.27s_theorem

Comment: @Gerald, I am just a physics student, and don't know much about vector measure. For vector measures will it require $\int_E f\ge0$ which I naively think it should be? but here f and g can be negative. Is there any more elementary way using only introductory real analysis for this problem?

Comment: No, nonnegative is not required for vector measure.